# Salvando informações em banco e enviando via post em Rails

Tags: html5, wordpress, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho uma view que explica um sistema e permite que o usuário envie conteúdo para publicação. Ele apenas digita em uma textarea e esse texto é enviado para um blog WP, junto com seu username e e-mail, que o transforma em um guest post.

O problema é que agora eu preciso fazer uma modificação para que, além de enviar os dados para o WP, o sistema os salve no banco MySQL associado ao Rails. O registro terá o nome do usuário, o seu e-mail e o título do artigo (pegando a substring entre as tags h1).

Fiz o scaffold para gerar a manipulação dos artigos, mas não consigo fazer essa parte de captura do título, pois não existe um $_POST como no PHP. Procurei em toda parte e não consegui encontrar uma solução satisfatória. Como posso fazer para que a informação seja salva no banco e, em seguida, enviada para o blog WP?

Trecho de código atual:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :nome_autor, @current_user.name %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :email_autor, @current_user.email %>
<textarea name = "texto"><h1>SEU TÍTULO AQUI</h1><br>Escreva seu artigo aqui e nos envie!</textarea>
<button type = "submit">Enviar Artigo</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eduardo, em seu controller dê uma olhada na variável params, ela é a responsável por transportar as informações do form para seu controller.

Em seu controller utilize o Model para salvar essas.

**Para salvar esse mesmo post no WP, eu nunca fiz isso, mas você pode criar uma conexão extra no Rails**

```
  @connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
              :adapter => "mysql2",
              :host => "localhost",
              :database => "wp_banco_de_dados",
              :username => "root",
              :password => "root123"
  )

  sql =  "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`,   `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...)";


  @result = @connection.connection.execute(sql);
```

Ideal é você criar uma Lib com essa conexão e passar o SQL a ser executado.
Não testei o código, mas a ideia é essa ai!

Comment: Mas como posso fazer o envio para a página de WP depois?

Comment: @Eduardo editei a resposta.